# Android studio , program is compatible with 6.0 ,but not with 7.0

Tags: android

I've got a program, which is working on android 6.0 without any error, but does not work on 7.0. I can start my program in 7.0, but when I want to use my camera in it, it quits everytime. What is the problem with that? ( In the android studio, it is set to be compatible from 6.0 to 7.1.1)

> 10-10 15:17:40.193 18001-18001/erdosk.stockidbp I/OpenCameraSource: Camera focus mode: continuous-picture is not supported on this device. 10-10 15:17:40.194 18001-18001/erdosk.stockidbp I/SurfaceView: 35685123 finishedDrawing, this = android.view.SurfaceView{2208303 V.E...... ......ID -28,0-629,876} 10-10 15:17:40.202 18001-18001/erdosk.stockidbp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM 10-10 15:17:40.216 18001-18001/erdosk.stockidbp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> Process: erdosk.stockidbp, PID: 18001 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.List.contains(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference at erdosk.stockidbp.camera.CameraSource.createCamera(CameraSource.java:510) at erdosk.stockidbp.camera.CameraSource.start(CameraSource.java:229) at erdosk.stockidbp.camera.CameraSourcePreview.startIfReady(CameraSourcePreview.java:82) at erdosk.stockidbp.camera.CameraSourcePreview.access$200(CameraSourcePreview.java:32) at erdosk.stockidbp.camera.CameraSourcePreview$SurfaceCallback.surfaceCreated(CameraSourcePreview.java:92) at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:709) at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:180) at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:944) at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2553) at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1462) at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6965) at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:907) at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:709) at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:644) at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:893) at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)

Comment: Could you post your LogCat with that error?

Comment: This is like saying to a mechanic "my car doesn't work". Without giving any information of what you've tried, where the error occurs, or anything. Post your code and post the logcat of the error.

Comment: Post your logcat error. But I think the problem is the fileprovider

Answer (score 1):

Looks like missing Runtime-Permission (to use camera). Or using "file://" URL with camera intent.